# Optimizing slow MySQL query

Tags: mysql

What's so slow in the following MySQL query?

I have tried adding indexes to DocumentRevision.document and Document.status but still it usually takes forever to execute the query (it seems that if a make this queries sequentially, the query speeds up). Is there another, more efficient way, to achieve the same result? The query fetches all the latest revisions of all documents available in the database. There are two tables. Document and DocumentRevision. Document table just contains id and status fields, while DocumentRevision contains all the data and also "document" id field so that it knows which document's revision it is.

```
SELECT rev.document as documentId, rev.id as revId, rev.name as name, 
       rev.dateCreated as dateCreated, rev.documentOrder as documentOrder
FROM (
    SELECT Document.id as docId, MAX(DocumentRevision.id) as maxRevId 
    FROM Document, DocumentRevision
    WHERE Document.id = DocumentRevision.document AND Document.status = 0 
    GROUP BY Document.id
) AS x 
INNER JOIN DocumentRevision as rev on rev.document = x.docId 
       AND rev.id = x.maxRevId 
ORDER BY dateCreated DESC;
```

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` say?

Comment: How many revisions (per document) are there in average? Are there lots of documents with no revisions at all?

Comment: Hundreds per average. There are not many documents without lots of revisions. Actually currently there are about >200 different documents.

Comment: Please provide your Create table (indexes , engine, keys , etc...)

Comment: is `DocumentRevision.id` a `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: DocumentRevision.id is PRIMARY KEY yes.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

```
SELECT  dr.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  document, MAX(id) AS maxid
        FROM    documentRevision
        GROUP BY
                document
        ) drd
JOIN    documentRevision dr
ON      dr.id = drd.maxid
JOIN    document d
ON      (d.id, d.status) = (drd.document, 0)
```

and

```
SELECT  dr.*
FROM    document d
JOIN    documentRevision dr
ON      dr.id =
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    documentRevision dri
        WHERE   dri.document = d.id
        ORDER BY
                document DESC, id DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

The first one will most probably be most efficient, unless you have really many revisions per document.

Create a composite index on `documentRevision (document, id)` (in this order) for the queries to work fast.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your requirement:

> There are two tables. Document and DocumentRevision. Document table
>   just contains id and status fields, while DocumentRevision contains
>   all the data and also "document" id field so that it knows which
>   document's revision it is.

And your code, I wrote another query without subselect. It should be more effective with just one select and proper indexes on document.ID and documentRevision.document to have a nice join performance.

```
SELECT rev.document docID, MAX(rev.id) revID, rev.name revName, rev.dateCreated dateCreated, rev.documentOrder docOrder
FROM DocumentRevisin as rev, Document as doc
WHERE doc.status = 0 AND doc.id = rev.document
GROUP BY rev.document, rev.name revName, rev.dateCreated dateCreated, rev.documentOrder docOrder
```

Comment: What makes you think `rev.*` will belong to the revisions with the greatest revision numbers?

Comment: Author wrote 'MAX(DocumentRevision.id) as maxRevId' this in code. And Document table only has id and status. Revision table has **all** revisions which means it also has the greatest revision number.

In original query only reference to 'Document' table is 'where status = 0' clause. And a join on ID column which is equal to 'DocumentRevision.document'

Without knowing the data and the whole table structures, this seems the shortest solution for this question.

Comment: Problem is that you are getting various columns from the documentRevision tablew hich are not aggregate columns or in the GROUP BY clause. Hence the values of these columns could belong to any of the revisions for that document id.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to add all columns but aggregated ones to group by clause. Now I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your subquery with a `GROUP BY` may cause some execution plan problems if the results are big; you may want to try the query without a subquery.

(Indexes on `Document.id`, `DocumentRevision.document` and `DocumentRevision.status` will help.)

```
SELECT rev.document as documentId, rev.id as revId, rev.name as name, 
   rev.dateCreated as dateCreated, rev.documentOrder as documentOrder
FROM Document doc
JOIN DocumentRevision rev
  ON doc.id=rev.document
LEFT JOIN DocumentRevision rev2
  ON rev.document = rev2.document AND rev.id < rev2.id
WHERE doc.status=0 AND rev2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY dateCreated DESC;
```

[SQLfiddle to show identical results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a83ab/2). Note the simpler plan for the query without subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Your query used the documentRevision table in join for more than once. There is certainly room for optimize.

In other DBMS (such as Teradata or MS SQL server, this can be accomplished by 'window aggregation' function in the form of `sum(1) over(partition by rev.document order by rev.id desc)`.

MySQL does not have window aggregation functions.
But the same can be done with parameters:

```
select * from (
  select
  if(@doc_id_grp=rev.document,@rank:=@rank+1,@rank:=1) rank /*the same document.id (documentRevision.document) is considered the same group, in the group, @rank increntally increases, when the doc_id changes, @rank resets to 0*/
  ,@doc_id_grp:=rev.document as doc_id
  ,rev.id as rev_id
  ,rev.name as name
  ,rev.datecreated as datecreated
  ,rev.documentorder as documentorder
  from Document doc
  join DocumentRevision rev
  on doc.id=rev.Document
  ,(select @rank:=0,@doc_id_grp:=0) a
  order by rev.document,rev.id desc
  where doc.status=0
) x
where rank=1
```

This way, the DBMS do not join the table twice but only join once and then do a sort.

I do not have a MySQL environment to test this upon, but tweak this as you need to. I hope this will be helpful.
Please also have index on Document.id and DocumentRevision.document to optimize the join.